# Speeding up Database Read/Write in Ajax By Calling a Different URL

Tags: ajax, database

Say I am using any PHP framework. When I make an AJAX call to update/read/write something from the db. The whole application will now have to run before my simple db call is executed.

Would it be a good idea to have, in the public folder, a file called `/public/db.php` so that I can then make AJAX calls to `db.php` and skip the framework startup?

Comment: Why do you need a framework then?

Comment: I want to make the AJAX calls. I know in the real world, companies run two servers, one for just read/write data to db in AJAX, and one that runs the actual program. So I wanted to mimic that on one server with two links.

Comment: "one for just read/write data to db in AJAX" --- o_O If you can do it easily - why not. It's your business